# Book about a man who suddenly finds himself in an unknown place and meets a humanoid who is quite different

Tags: story-identification, novel

The story is about a man suddenly finding himself in an unknown place. He meets a humanoid who is yet quite different. Similarly, the man is obviously alien to these beings around him. The humanoid takes the man home and hides him from others who seek to apprehend him. The man goes on a mission and helps his benefactor. At the end, the man's friend, who is in the 3rd dimension, recognizes his friend, who's changed dimensions (4th dimension.) But the man disappears into the forest.

I read this book in the 1960's. I'm not sure if it's classified as "juvenile" or "adult." I think the man somehow enters a 4th or alternate dimensional world. Please help me find it!!! Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain more about the 3rd/4th dimension bt? It is unclear, at least to me, what that means in this context. Is it just that parallel worlds exist side by side in a 4th dimension, or is there more to it?

Comment: Thanks for responding to my post, Klaus! I think that there was another world so close to our 3-D world that the main character entered it by accident. Everything he saw was somehow out of focus, perhaps fractured like reflections in a house of mirrors. I hope this makes things a little clearer. Thanks again!

Comment: It just might be Hannes Bok's *Beyond the Golden Stair*, which takes the protagonist to a mysterious 4-dimensional world. However, the book version of the original 1948 story wasn't published until 1970. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_the_Golden_Stair

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I haven't read it, but I'd like to!!